# PHP Array Search from array

Tags: php, arrays

well, as usual i'm not good at explaining what i want in the title, and here's my question:

i have this array (which eventually doesn't work, and gives illegal offset type error.

```
protected $files = [
     ['jpeg','bmp']  =>  'images',
     ['mp4','avi']   =>  'videos',
 ]
```

this method is what i want.

```
public function getType($extension){
    // my question is related to this method right here.
}
```

this is the test area

```
var_dump( (new FileDetector())->getType('jpeg') ); // this should return 'image'
```

so the idea right here is searching the array of $files.

however the first error i get while writing things like that is '`Illegal offset type`' i cannot create an array which looks like this :

```
[ 
  ['jpg', ...] => 'images',
  ['avi', ...] => 'videos'
]
```

it works the other way around like

```
[ 
  'images' => ['jpg', ...],
  'videos' => ['avi', ...],
]
```

if you have time, can you explain to me why the first one doesn't work, or a hint regarding that error so i can look online etc...

second is my main question, there are lots of ways to achieve what i want but i want the **best practice** and this one to me looks like the cleanest way.

thank you for your time. and i hope my request is clear.

Comment: comma separated indexes is a very bad idea. convert like this:- `protected $files = [
 'jpeg' => 'images',
 'bmp'  =>  'images',
 'mp4'  => 'videos',
 'avi'    =>  'videos'
 ]`

Comment: Go with the second option (i.e. 'images' as key) as this will stop duplicating data.

Comment: @NigelRen apparently that's my only way, cuz in one answer a guy answered why the first one doesn't work, now what's the best practice to search that array, for instance... now i can go and do array_search on images/videos, but that's two or (x the amount of keys i have) searches. 
something literal like : search the array of $files for the type jpeg and return 'image'

Comment: The alternative of repeating the elements (i.e. 'jpg' =>  'images', 'bmp' => 'images' ) duplicates a lot of the data, it's quicker to work with IF your mainly working from extension to type.  Also have to be careful as MP4 can be audio only (so would you have MP4 as audio AND video?).

Comment: @NigelRen well it doesn't have to be array thing, i just don't feel like repeating myself like you said, but i have no experience at something else, not on my mind at least, however i found things like serialize, i don't know if that would work.

Answer (score 2):

For the first part of the question, php arrays are associative arrays, meaning they can have only one value as key. Associative arrays are key value pairs, where for one key there exists multiple values but not wise versa. Therefore you are getting error for this

```
[ 
  ['jpg', ...] => 'images',
  ['avi', ...] => 'videos'
]
```

and not for this

```
[ 
  'images' => ['jpg', ...],
  'videos' => ['avi', ...],
]
```

better approach to deal with this would be

**case 1:**

```
[ 
  'images' => ['jpg', ...],
  'videos' => ['avi', ...],
]
```

or 
**case 2**

```
[ 
  'jpg' => ['images'],
  'bmp' => ['images'],
  'avi' => ['videos'],
  'mp4' => ['videos'],
]
```

now as you can see, case one is compact,not redundant, so go ahead with case 1 as a better approach among 2.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yea the case 2 was the obvious solution, but the way [ ... ] =>  value seems clean, now since it doesn't work, we can skip that.

Comment: In some languages associative arrays can have keys of different types.  In Php keys can be integers or strings.  They are heterogeneous - a single array can have keys of different types.

Comment: yeah, keys are heterogeneous, but at same time, their cannot be multiple keys.

Comment: Of course you can have more than one key, you just can't use an array for an associative array as a key in Php.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to set up an associative array with an array as a key!

Man page: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

> The key can either be an integer or a string. The value can be of any type.

NOTE:

> PHP arrays can contain integer and string keys at the same time as PHP
>   does not distinguish between indexed and associative arrays.

try this instead:

```
protected $files = [
    'jpeg' => 'images',
    'bmp'=> 'images',
    'mp4' =>  'videos',
    'avi' => 'videos'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you swap your keys and values (you can't use an array for a key in a Php array), we can iterate through the list until we find the extension you are after.

```
<?php
$type_extensions = [
     'images' => ['jpeg','bmp'],
     'videos' => ['mp4','avi']
];    

$get_type_from_extension = function($extension) use ($type_extensions) {
    foreach($type_extensions as $type => $extensions) {
        if(in_array($extension, $extensions)) 
            return $type;
    }
};

var_dump($get_type_from_extension('mp4'));
var_dump($get_type_from_extension('ogg'));
```

Output

```
string 'videos' (length=6)
null
```